# Debugging with Dev-C++ 5.2.0.2 - Cannot find program file gdb.exe when debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, dev-c++

I am using Orwell Dev-C++ 5.2.0.2 on 32-bit Windows XP. The compiler is TDM-GCC 4.6.1 32-bit. Whenever I press F8 to debug, a error box appears, which says:

```
Error with debugging process : could not find program file gdb.exe.
```

Pressing Enter, another error box appears, which says:

```
Error with debugging process : CloseHandle - gdb process
```

Then the debugging process stops. I can't debug. I have checked that gdb.exe exists in C:\Dev-Cpp\bin. Why couldn't it be found? Anyone can help? Thank you!

Comment: Mind telling us _what_ the problem was and _how_ you solved it? Add it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Actually, gdb.exe in the 5.2.0.2 package is a 64-bit exe file. I downloaded a 32-bit version and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should add C:\Dev-Cpp\bin to your PATH environment variable.

Here's how: http://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: There is also a chance that installer did that but reboot or something is needed for settings to take an effect.

Comment: I tried setting PATH and rebooting, but the same error occurs. :-(

Answer (score -1):

You need to include C:\Dev-Cpp\bin in PATH to get this to work.